# How to customize a UIview with two UIbutton

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to custmoize a `UIview` with two `UIbutton` where user can pass parameter to the customize class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    CanvasView *newCanvas = [[CanvasView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 164.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-350)];
    self.canvas = newCanvas;
    [self.view addSubview:canvas];

}
```

I can only customize the `UIView`! how to add the two `UIButton` to View.

When I allocate the `UIView` Custom Class it need to visible `UIButtons` too

Comment: cant understand what u mean by >`I can only customize the UIView`

Comment: @samfisher!  i am customizing UIView where my UIview do have two button's add on UIview!  when i allocated UIview, custom class i need to appear two buttons where i can sent frame where i need the button to that custom class!

Comment: Did the custom view had already the two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic buttons using the following code

```
CanvasView *newCanvas = [[CanvasView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 164.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-350)];
self.canvas = newCanvas;
[self.view addSubview:newCanvas];


UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
[but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[newCanvas addSubview:but];
```

You can either use the insertSubview:atIndex method

```
 [newCanvas insertSubview:myButton atIndex:0];
```

Hope it helps you.